# Preloading classes without Rails?

Tags: ruby, performance, spork

I am working on a big project, and I realized that several of the components were groups of classes that I could turn into services and strip from Rails.  But now that I've done that I realize that the slowness of loading classes without Spork isn't a function of Rails being slow, but a function of Ruby being slow.  Is there something like Spork that will work in non Rails projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spork should work just fine for any ruby project, it just requires a bit more setup.

Assuming you're using `rspec 2.x` and `spork 0.9`, make a `spec_helper.rb` that looks something like:

```
require 'spork'

# the rspec require seems to be necessary, 
# without it you get "Missing or uninitialized constant: Object::RSpec" errors
require 'rspec' 

Spork.prefork do

  # do expensive one-time setup here
  require 'mylibrary'
  MyLibrary.setup_lots_of_stuff

end

Spork.each_run do

  # do setup that must be done on each test run here (setting up external state, etc):
  MyLibrary.reset_db

end
```

Everything in the `Spork.prefork` block will only be run once (at spork startup), the rest will run on every test invocation.

If you have lots of framework-specific setup, you'd probably be better off making an AppFramework for your library. See the [padrino AppFramework](https://github.com/timcharper/spork/blob/master/lib/spork/app_framework/padrino.rb) for an example.